# nginx: redirect mobile requests to /mobile/$uri

Tags: redirect, proxy, nginx

I am trying to setup my nginx to redirect all the requests from mobile devices to /mobile/$uri
i came up with this solution but it doesn't seem to work. Is it a syntax problem or a misunderstanding of the whole redirecting concept.

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry)') {
     rewrite     ^(.*)   http://xxxx.org/mobile/$1 permanent;
}
```

When i use my android phone i am getting something like xxx.org/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile....

Any ideas?Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    #initliaze mobile
    set $mobile "";

    if ($request_uri !~* "^/mobile.*" ){
        set $mobile Y;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry) ) {
        set $mobile "${mobile}E";
    }

    if ( $http_referer !~* "xxx\.org" ){
       set $mobile "${mobile}S";
    }

    if ( $host ~* "xxx\.org" ){
       set $mobile "${mobile}S";
    }

    if ($mobile = YESS){
        rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/mobile$request_uri ;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use different locations:

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry)') {
        return 301 /mobile$request_uri;
    }
}

location /mobile/ {

}
```

btw, http://nginx.org/r/return

Comment: Depends on your needs. It may be empty and therefore inherit some values from the parent context. Or it can contain any configuration that you need, and any nested locations.

Answer (score 5):

Use http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ It has scripts for all webservers and client/server side languages.

Comment: i want to detect if it is a mobile device in the nginx config